# i want to run a program to perform click on google apps icon using Selenium WebDriver but on running the code, it directs to google product page

Tags: java, selenium

I want to run a program to perform click on google apps icon using Selenium WebDriver but on running the code, it navigates to google product page.
Pease help me to fix this issue.

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gbwa']/div[1]/a")).click();
```

Comment: Try `html/body/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a` as xpath :)

Comment: It still navigates to the same URL  "https://www.google.co.in/intl/en/about/products/"

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gbwa']")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gbwa']/div[1]")).click();
```

Comment: On giving quotes to gbwa it is showing error (The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable) in Eclipse.

Comment: It should be single quotes

Comment: On entering single quotes it still navigates to the same URL "google.co.in/intl/en/about/products/"

Answer (score 0):

Please try to click on the link and not on the div.

Use one of these selectors:

Xpath: `//*[@id='gbwa']//a[contains(@href, 'options')]`

css: `#gbwa a[href*=options]`

Comment: still having same problem

Comment: the selectors are ok, i don't think the issue is from here, try to use as url `https://www.google.co.in`

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'gb_b') and contains(@class, 'gb_4b')]"));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: ok, so the reason that doesn't work anymore is that one of the classes names changed. thus using just one class should work.
I have just tried and all three of these work for me:
       `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gbwa\"]/div[1]/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.className("gb_b")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#gbwa > div.gb_Ec > a")).click();`

Comment: The complete method I used is this:

`@Test
    public void check(){
        TestName("Random check");

        driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
        wait(3);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gbwa\"]/div[1]/a")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.className("gb_b")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#gbwa > div.gb_Ec > a")).click();
    }`

Comment: I have noticed that the menu doesn't visibly open unless the browser is in focus, so you might want to try to do that too.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.gb_Lf")).click();
WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id,'I0')]"));
driver.switchTo().frame(ele);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='YouTube']")).click();
```